# Redirect to homnepage fails: header already sent

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

Hi whenever a user enters their details on my login screen, I end up with the following error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/2/a/e/somedomain.co.uk/httpd.www/Francium/logSys/example-two-step-login/login.php:14) in /customers/2/a/e/somedmain.co.uk/httpd.www/Francium/logSys/class.logsys.php on line 448 Warning:

```
setcookie(
  "logSyslogin",
  hash("sha256", self::$config['keys']['cookie'] . $us_id . self::$config['keys']['cookie']),
  strtotime(self::$config['cookies']['expire']),
  self::$config['cookies']['path'], self::$config['cookies']['domain']
);
```

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/2/a/e/somedomain.co.uk/httpd.www/Francium/logSys/example-two-step-login/login.php:14) in /customers/2/a/e/somedomain.co.uk/httpd.www/Francium/logSys/class.logsys.php on line 1060

```
public static function redirect($url, $status = 302){
  header("Location: $url", true, $status);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Made the question at least readable, added propper tagging.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an output at line 14 if your `login.php`. If you echo something, php have to send headers in order for your browser to be able to display it. Once they are sent, you can't modify them